# UIButton reused in UITableViewCell when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

In my UITableView, there are header cells and standard cells. Each standard cell has a check box (a `UIButton`) added to it, using the following two methods.

**Method below is called to create each `UITableViewCell`:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"activityIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

// HEADER ROWS
if (indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 5 || indexPath.row == 10 || indexPath.row == 15 || indexPath.row == 20 || indexPath.row == 25 || indexPath.row == 30) {

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"Yeaa!");
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [activityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aliquam" size:13.0f];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    static int a = 20.0f;
    tableView.rowHeight = a;

} else {
    // STANDARD ROWS
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
        NSLog(@"Standard cell is nil");

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [activityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aliquam" size:20.0f];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    static int b = 44.0f;
    tableView.rowHeight = b;
}

// CREATE CHECK BOXES IN STANDARD ROWS
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actMondayMorning];
    [cell addSubview:actMondayMorning];
} else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actMondayAfternoon];
    [cell addSubview:actMondayAfternoon];
} else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actMondayEvening];
    [cell addSubview:actMondayEvening];
} else if (indexPath.row == 4) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actMondayNight];
    [cell addSubview:actMondayNight];
} else if (indexPath.row == 6) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actTuesdayMorning];
    [cell addSubview:actTuesdayMorning];
} else if (indexPath.row == 7) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actTuesdayAfternoon];
    [cell addSubview:actTuesdayAfternoon];
} else if (indexPath.row == 8) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actTuesdayEvening];
    [cell addSubview:actTuesdayEvening];
} else if (indexPath.row == 9) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actTuesdayNight];
    [cell addSubview:actTuesdayNight];
} else if (indexPath.row == 11) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actWednesdayMorning];
    [cell addSubview:actWednesdayMorning];
} else if (indexPath.row == 12) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actWednesdayAfternoon];
    [cell addSubview:actWednesdayAfternoon];
} else if (indexPath.row == 13) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actWednesdayEvening];
    [cell addSubview:actWednesdayEvening];
} else if (indexPath.row == 14) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actWednesdayNight];
    [cell addSubview:actWednesdayNight];
} else if (indexPath.row == 16) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actThursdayMorning];
    [cell addSubview:actThursdayMorning];
} else if (indexPath.row == 17) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actThursdayAfternoon];
    [cell addSubview:actThursdayAfternoon];
} else if (indexPath.row == 18) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actThursdayEvening];
    [cell addSubview:actThursdayEvening];
} else if (indexPath.row == 19) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actThursdayNight];
    [cell addSubview:actThursdayNight];
} else if (indexPath.row == 21) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actFridayMorning];
    [cell addSubview:actFridayMorning];
} else if (indexPath.row == 22) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actFridayAfternoon];
    [cell addSubview:actFridayAfternoon];
} else if (indexPath.row == 23) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actFridayEvening];
    [cell addSubview:actFridayEvening];
} else if (indexPath.row == 24) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actFridayNight];
    [cell addSubview:actFridayNight];
} else if (indexPath.row == 26) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actSaturdayMorning];
    [cell addSubview:actSaturdayMorning];
} else if (indexPath.row == 27) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actSaturdayAfternoon];
    [cell addSubview:actSaturdayAfternoon];
} else if (indexPath.row == 28) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actSaturdayEvening];
    [cell addSubview:actSaturdayEvening];
} else if (indexPath.row == 29) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actSaturdayNight];
    [cell addSubview:actSaturdayNight];
} else if (indexPath.row == 31) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actSundayMorning];
    [cell addSubview:actSundayMorning];
} else if (indexPath.row == 32) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actSundayAfternoon];
    [cell addSubview:actSundayAfternoon];
} else if (indexPath.row == 33) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actSundayEvening];
    [cell addSubview:actSundayEvening];
} else if (indexPath.row == 34) {
    [self createRoleCheckbox:actSundayNight];
    [cell addSubview:actSundayNight];
}

return cell;
}
```

**Method below is called to create the checkboxes (`UIButton`):**

```
- (void) createRoleCheckbox:(UIButton *)passedButton {

passedButton.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth-checkboxDiameter-(checkboxInset/2), (checkboxInset/2), checkboxDiameter, checkboxDiameter);

[passedButton setImage:checkboxImageUnselected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[passedButton setImage:checkboxImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

if (passedButton == actMondayMorning)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actMondayMorningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actMondayAfternoon)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actMondayAfternoonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actMondayEvening)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actMondayEveningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actMondayNight)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actMondayNightPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actTuesdayMorning)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actTuesdayMorningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actTuesdayAfternoon)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actTuesdayAfternoonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actTuesdayEvening)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actTuesdayEveningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actTuesdayNight)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actTuesdayNightPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actWednesdayMorning)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actWednesdayMorningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actWednesdayAfternoon)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actWednesdayAfternoonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actWednesdayEvening)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actWednesdayEveningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actWednesdayNight)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actWednesdayNightPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actThursdayMorning)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actThursdayMorningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actThursdayAfternoon)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actThursdayAfternoonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actThursdayEvening)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actThursdayEveningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actThursdayNight)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actThursdayNightPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actFridayMorning)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actFridayMorningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actFridayAfternoon)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actFridayAfternoonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actFridayEvening)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actFridayEveningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actFridayNight)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actFridayNightPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actSaturdayMorning)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actSaturdayMorningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actSaturdayAfternoon)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actSaturdayAfternoonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actSaturdayEvening)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actSaturdayEveningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actSaturdayNight)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actSaturdayNightPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actSundayMorning)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actSundayMorningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actSundayAfternoon)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actSundayAfternoonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actSundayEvening)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actSundayEveningPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
else if (passedButton == actSundayNight)
    [passedButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actSundayNightPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

This code correctly creates check boxes in each row.

However, when I scroll through my app, the `UIButton`s duplicate, randomly appearing in the header cells.

In addition, if I click a button, putting it in its selected state, when I scroll, other buttons will randomly also be selected state also, even when I did not press them.

In short, the `UIButton`s are being reused. How can I this from happening?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add your buttons to the contentView of the cell, and then clear out the contentView, remove everything before you add your buttons. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this would be done (ideally with some basic example code), and why it would work? Based on your description, surely simply adding and immediately removing a UIButton from a contentView (or _anything_) would have no net effect?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code.

You should have a different identifier for each structurally different type of cell you create.

If your header cells have different elements than your "standard" cells, have your cellForRowAtIndexPath method first decide if this is a header row or not. If it is a header row, call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier with the ID for a header cell. If not, call it with the identifier for a "standard" cell.

That way you'll only get a recycled cell if one of the correct type is available, and you'll never get a header cell when you want a "standard" cell.

Comment: This stops the UIButtons appearing in the header, thank you. However, the main concern of me selecting a cell at the top of the TableView, scrolling down, and having a random cell also be in selected state hasn't changed unfortunately. I can scroll up and down, and the selected-state UIButton will switch cells at random.

Answer (score 0):

First I strongly recommend not creating “header” cells, using sections instead you won't need to make the conditional for specific indexPath rows.

On the other hand it's not clear how do you create your buttons, but as far as I can see you're just adding a button each time the cell is displayed on the screen, also it's not clear how the indexPath.rows is passed to the createRoleCheckbox method, since it only takes an UIButton as a parameter.

In any case I don't think it's a good idea to create a button depending on the row, I'd create a single button, and change the selector (and the title I suppose) depending on the row, something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"activityIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    // Since you switched to section they are all standard rows now
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
            NSLog(@"Standard cell is nil");

    }

    UIButton *cellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    cellButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 150.0, 30.0);
    [cell addSubview:cellButton];

    cell.textLabel.text = [activityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aliquam" size:20.0f];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    static int b = 44.0f;
    tableView.rowHeight = b;


    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
         [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(appropiateMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [cellButton setTitle:@"Appropiate Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
         [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(appropiateMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [cellButton setTitle:@"Appropiate Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
         [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(appropiateMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [cellButton setTitle:@"Appropiate Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } ...

    return cell;
}
```

This approach will all make the createRoleCheckbox method completely unnecessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This stops UIButtons from appearing in the header rows, but unfortunately still doesn't solve the duplication error. If I select a cell at the top of the TableView, then scroll to the bottom, a randomly selected UIButton will be in selected state. I can then scroll up and down, and the selected buttons will move positions, though the one I actually selected remains put.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. It's a bit of a ghetto solution, and I'm sure purists will likely take issue with it (to be honest, it may somehow cause memory issues, but that shouldn't be an issue for my app, given the view controller is only briefly open).

First, I replaced `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];` with `UITableViewCell *cell`.

I then replaced `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];` with `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];`. My code is technically slightly different to this, but this is the essence of what I did. I figured I would stop the code reusing the buttons by, well, stopping it reusing the buttons. Hopefully this helps someone in the future, and doesn't cause more problems than it solves.